# How to create TextMate project that contains all files in a folder (and updates dynamically)?

Tags: textmate

I'd like to create a TextMate project that consists of all files in a particular folder, with the added stipulation that as files are added to (or removed from) that folder that they be added/removed from the TextMate project.

Is this possible?

I'd love to have a TextMate project that can mirror the list of files being worked with by the folder storing Elements files...

Comment: Instead of drag n droppin, I find really useful the [Open in Textmate](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/open-in-textmate-from-leopard-finder) Finder toolbar icon. Updating files should work either way though..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it how it's working already?

I just tried drag'n'dropping a folder on the Textmate icon, it opens in "project mode", then I added a file to the folder, which Textmate did too, when gaining focus. And deleting the file and focusing Textmate made it disappear from the project pane.

Comment: Another +1. This is how TextMate projects work for me by default.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a TextMate project, there's two "folder"-ish concepts: Groups (beige icon) and Folders (blue icon).

Groups are things that exist only inside the project, and let you organize references to files however you see fit, without affecting the external location of those files.

Folders are references to actual folders. This is what you want. To add a folder reference to an existing project, just drag the folder from the Finder onto the project drawer.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed work this way, though the project tree can be slow to update if you're adding files on the fly (for example, using "save as...")

Answer (score 0):

TextMate doesn't do a good job of creating .jar projects for you. I think they are still working on it, but I couldn't find a proper way to make a project using TextMate. Actually, it might be that they do have a feature for making projects, but I just didn't find out.

After you use TextMate to compile and get all the necessary class files, use another code editor like Eclipse or NetBeans and make a project from there. That's what I did...

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the TextMate app to the Mac's Dock (the floating dashboard menu)
2. Drag & Drop the Project's Directory over the TextMate Icon on the Dock
3. Then you can refine project settings in Preferences → Project